# org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: in geckodriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

Once in a while I get an alertbox that crashes my test. I did add the following line to my code, but I still get the following exception

```
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
```

Below is the exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: : 
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
System info: host: 'firefox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-36-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 58.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 10211, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.yshC1I..., moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.13.0-36-generic, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: c995dd63-3b01-4c6f-84cd-4434bb104829
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=titletextonly}
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
        at clscraper.Scraper.run(Scraper.java:68)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: : 
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z'
System info: host: 'firefox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-36-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 58.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 10211, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile.yshC1I..., moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 4.13.0-36-generic, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: c995dd63-3b01-4c6f-84cd-4434bb104829
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.close(RemoteWebDriver.java:487)
        at clscraper.Scraper.run(Scraper.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: @KirilS. it's not a duplicate. I'm getting unexpected results.

Comment: did you read the accepted answer?

Comment: @KirilS. yes I read that before I posted this

Comment: Found out it's not supported in the geckodriver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/990

Comment: that solution catches the exception in case of UnhandledAlertException and in case of no alert, and prints what alert had to say. So... what in that solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: the try catch method may work. you are right. When I looked at that I did not know that `UnexpectedAlertBehaviour` is not implemented in Geckodriver